# How can I include more characters in GET request URL

Tags: forms, url, get

I want to submit many textareas contents of a form via GET request but it is not allowing me to as GET URL has length restriction. I don't want to use POST for this project as I am using the submitted URL to get contents of the form. So how can I increase the no. of characters in the GET URL?

Answer (score 0):

Since, I didn't hear from anybody, I decided to switch to POST method excluding the feature that I wanted to perform with GET method. I think it is impossible to increase the limit of the number of characters supported by GET method.